# remove uploaded file from my php folder

Tags: php

i have given demo link

http://exposureroom.biz/upload.aspx
here i am implementing ajax file upload process-bar in my website so here i want to add Delete button for remove uploaded files.

js file :

```
// common variables
var iBytesUploaded = 0;
var iBytesTotal = 0;
var iPreviousBytesLoaded = 0;
var iMaxFilesize = 1048576; // 1MB
var oTimer = 0;
var sResultFileSize = '';

function secondsToTime(secs) { // we will use this function to convert seconds in normal time format
    var hr = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    var min = Math.floor((secs - (hr * 3600))/60);
    var sec = Math.floor(secs - (hr * 3600) -  (min * 60));

    if (hr < 10) {hr = "0" + hr; }
    if (min < 10) {min = "0" + min;}
    if (sec < 10) {sec = "0" + sec;}
    if (hr) {hr = "00";}
    return hr + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
};

function bytesToSize(bytes) {
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB'];
    if (bytes == 0) return 'n/a';
    var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
    return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(1) + ' ' + sizes[i];
};

function fileSelected() {

    // hide different warnings
    document.getElementById('upload_response').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('error2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('abort').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('warnsize').style.display = 'none';

    // get selected file element
    var oFile = document.getElementById('image_file').files[0];

    // filter for image files
    var rFilter = /^(image\/bmp|image\/gif|image\/jpeg|image\/png|image\/tiff)$/i;
    if (! rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
        document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'block';
        return;
    }

    // little test for filesize
    if (oFile.size > iMaxFilesize) {
        document.getElementById('warnsize').style.display = 'block';
        return;
    }

    // get preview element
    var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');

    // prepare HTML5 FileReader
    var oReader = new FileReader();
        oReader.onload = function(e){

        // e.target.result contains the DataURL which we will use as a source of the image
        oImage.src = e.target.result;

        oImage.onload = function () { // binding onload event

            // we are going to display some custom image information here
            sResultFileSize = bytesToSize(oFile.size);
            document.getElementById('fileinfo').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('filename').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + oFile.name;
            document.getElementById('filesize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + sResultFileSize;
            document.getElementById('filetype').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + oFile.type;
            document.getElementById('filedim').innerHTML = 'Dimension: ' + oImage.naturalWidth + ' x ' + oImage.naturalHeight;
        };
    };

    // read selected file as DataURL
    oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}

function startUploading() {
    // cleanup all temp states
    iPreviousBytesLoaded = 0;
    document.getElementById('upload_response').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('error2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('abort').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('warnsize').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('progress_percent').innerHTML = '';
    var oProgress = document.getElementById('progress');
    oProgress.style.display = 'block';
    oProgress.style.width = '0px';

    // get form data for POSTing
    //var vFD = document.getElementById('upload_form').getFormData(); // for FF3
    var vFD = new FormData(document.getElementById('upload_form')); 

    // create XMLHttpRequest object, adding few event listeners, and POSTing our data
    var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();        
    oXHR.upload.addEventListener('progress', uploadProgress, false);
    oXHR.addEventListener('load', uploadFinish, false);
    oXHR.addEventListener('error', uploadError, false);
    oXHR.addEventListener('abort', uploadAbort, false);
    oXHR.open('POST', 'upload.php');
    oXHR.send(vFD);

    // set inner timer
    oTimer = setInterval(doInnerUpdates, 300);
}

function doInnerUpdates() { // we will use this function to display upload speed
    var iCB = iBytesUploaded;
    var iDiff = iCB - iPreviousBytesLoaded;

    // if nothing new loaded - exit
    if (iDiff == 0)
        return;

    iPreviousBytesLoaded = iCB;
    iDiff = iDiff * 2;
    var iBytesRem = iBytesTotal - iPreviousBytesLoaded;
    var secondsRemaining = iBytesRem / iDiff;

    // update speed info
    var iSpeed = iDiff.toString() + 'B/s';
    if (iDiff > 1024 * 1024) {
        iSpeed = (Math.round(iDiff * 100/(1024*1024))/100).toString() + 'MB/s';
    } else if (iDiff > 1024) {
        iSpeed =  (Math.round(iDiff * 100/1024)/100).toString() + 'KB/s';
    }

    document.getElementById('speed').innerHTML = iSpeed;
    document.getElementById('remaining').innerHTML = '| ' + secondsToTime(secondsRemaining);        
}

function uploadProgress(e) { // upload process in progress
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        iBytesUploaded = e.loaded;
        iBytesTotal = e.total;
        var iPercentComplete = Math.round(e.loaded * 100 / e.total);
        var iBytesTransfered = bytesToSize(iBytesUploaded);

        document.getElementById('progress_percent').innerHTML = iPercentComplete.toString() + '%';
        document.getElementById('progress').style.width = (iPercentComplete * 4).toString() + 'px';
        document.getElementById('b_transfered').innerHTML = iBytesTransfered;
        if (iPercentComplete == 100) {
            var oUploadResponse = document.getElementById('upload_response');
            oUploadResponse.innerHTML = '<h1>Please wait...processing</h1>';
            oUploadResponse.style.display = 'block';
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
    }
}

function uploadFinish(e) { // upload successfully finished
    var oUploadResponse = document.getElementById('upload_response');
    oUploadResponse.innerHTML = e.target.responseText;
    oUploadResponse.style.display = 'block';

    document.getElementById('progress_percent').innerHTML = '100%';
    document.getElementById('progress').style.width = '400px';
    document.getElementById('filesize').innerHTML = sResultFileSize;
    document.getElementById('remaining').innerHTML = '| 00:00:00';

    clearInterval(oTimer);
}

function uploadError(e) { // upload error
    document.getElementById('error2').style.display = 'block';
    clearInterval(oTimer);
}  

function uploadAbort(e) { // upload abort
    document.getElementById('abort').style.display = 'block';
    clearInterval(oTimer);
}
```

html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Pure HTML5 file upload | Script Tutorials</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h2>Pure HTML5 file upload</h2>
            <a href="http://www.script-tutorials.com/pure-html5-file-upload/" class="stuts">Back to original tutorial on <span>Script Tutorials</span></a>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="contr"><h2>You can select the file (image) and click Upload button</h2></div>

            <div class="upload_form_cont">
                <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
                    <div>
                        <div><label for="image_file">Please select image file</label></div>
                        <div><input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelected();" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="startUploading()" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="fileinfo">
                        <div id="filename"></div>
                        <div id="filesize"></div>
                        <div id="filetype"></div>
                        <div id="filedim"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="error">You should select valid image files only!</div>
                    <div id="error2">An error occurred while uploading the file</div>
                    <div id="abort">The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection</div>
                    <div id="warnsize">Your file is very big. We can't accept it. Please select more small file</div>

                    <div id="progress_info">
                        <div id="progress"></div>
                        <div id="progress_percent">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="clear_both"></div>
                        <div>
                            <div id="speed">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div id="remaining">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div id="b_transfered">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="clear_both"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="upload_response"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <img id="preview" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
        if($_FILES["image_file"]){


                 $uploads_dir = 'files/';

                $sFileName = $_FILES['file_name']['name'];
                $sFileType = $_FILES['file_name']['type'];
                function bytesToSize1024($bytes, $precision = 2) {
                  $unit = array('B','KB','MB');
                  return @round($bytes / pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($bytes, 1024)))), $precision).' '.$unit[$i];
        }
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'], "$uploads_dir/$sFileName");
                exit;

                }

                ?>
```

Comment: here i want to add delete button when i will upload my file like : http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your PHP script to

```
<?php

function bytesToSize1024($bytes, $precision = 2) {
    $unit = array('B','KB','MB');
    return @round($bytes / pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($bytes, 1024)))), $precision).' '.$unit[$i];
}

$uploads_dir = 'files/';

$sFileName = $_FILES['image_file']['name'];
$sFileType = $_FILES['image_file']['type'];
$sFileSize = bytesToSize1024($_FILES['image_file']['size'], 1);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'],$uploads_dir.$sFileName);

echo <<<EOF
<p>Your file: {$sFileName} has been successfully received.</p>
<p>Type: {$sFileType}</p>
<p>Size: {$sFileSize}</p>
EOF;

?>
```

create a file for deleting uploaded file

```
<?php
unlink($_POST['filename']);
echo 'Deleted';
?>
```

add another file for displaying your uploaded files you can change it as you want

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function deleteFile(file) {
    $('#delFile').hide();
    var order = 'filename='+file;
    $.post("delfilephp.php", order,  function(response,status, xhr){

                        if (status == "success") {
                            alert(response);

                        }
                        else if (status == "error") {
                            alert('Something went wrong, we are working to fix it'); 
                        }
                });

}
</script>

<div id="delFile">
<?php
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "files/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.*");

//print each file name
foreach($images as $image)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $image;
    ?>
 <a href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteFile('<?php echo $image; ?>')">Delete File</a>
<?php
}
?>

</div>
```